# Powerpoint slides (shapes) don't seem to inherit alternative text from master

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I would like to replace an element in my powerpoint slides to have a sense of document property variables. I do have the macro in place, and it works.

But I don't understand why slides created, and based on a master don't have any alternative text.  The master does have alternative text.  This makes me unable to loop over the properties.

Did I miss a setting somewhere ?

---

Master template:

[image: view of master template showing alternative text]

Slide based on this master layout:

[image: view of slide based on master, without alternative text]

Comment: You haven't missed anything. This might be a bug/oversight or by design, though I can't understand why it'd be deliberately designed that way.

Comment: What is the best strategy then to loop over each slide and have the section name placed in the slide ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In most cases, there won't be multiple master/layout placeholders of a given type (e.g. Title, Subtitle etc) so you can match the placeholder type of a slide shape to the placeholder type of the slide's layout.  Here's some example VBA:

```
Option Explicit

Sub TestThis()

    Dim osl As Slide
    Dim osh As Shape
    Dim sTemp As String
    
    For Each osl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each osh In osl.Shapes
           sTemp = MasterAltText(osh)
           If Len(sTemp) > 0 Then
                MsgBox sTemp
           End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub

Function MasterAltText(osh As Shape) As String

    Dim osl As Slide
    Dim oMasterShape As Shape
    Dim oLayout As CustomLayout
    
    ' Is this actually a placeholder?
    If Not osh.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
        MasterAltText = ""
    End If
    
    Set osl = osh.Parent
    Set oLayout = osl.CustomLayout
    
    For Each oMasterShape In oLayout.Shapes
        If oMasterShape.Type = msoPlaceholder Then
            If oMasterShape.PlaceholderFormat.Type _
              = osh.PlaceholderFormat.Type Then
                MasterAltText = oMasterShape.AlternativeText
                Exit Function
            End If
        End If
    Next

    MasterAltText = ""

End Function
```

Comment: Steve, this is an interesting approach. I have an idea on how to approach this. If it works, I will post my result and accept this as solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have digged a bit on this one, and have to conclude that seeing slide masters as "template" for each slide is really broken.

Apparently *none* of the properties for tags or alternative text set on placeholders / text frames in master slides are carried over to the slide that is based on the master. So thinking that a VBA code can loop over the shapes based on tag is not possible - unless the properties are set in each slide.

One hack I found is to use the font and position properties. This way, it's fairly simple to single out a shape.

Something along

```vb
    For Each processPage In Application.ActivePresentation.Slides
       For Each shapeobj In processPage.Shapes
           If shapeobj.TextFrame.TextRange.Font.Italic <> 0 Then
               ' found some shape with ITALIC text
               ' do things to it
           End If
 
           ' check against a const with section position
           '  Global Const sectiontop as Double = 27.95
           ' 
           If Round(shapeobj.TextFrame2.TextRange.BoundTop, 2) = sectiontop Then
               ' found shape based on position
               ' do things to it
           End If
        Next  ' shap
    Next 'slide
```

Comment: On the one hand, you're asking for the alt text from placeholders on master slides/layouts, but later, you've mentioned wanting to put the section name on each slide. Do you mean section name in PowerPoint's use of the term, or something else? See proposed answer for a way of retrieving alt text.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution that works for me, inspired by Steve Rindsberg.

I loop over the shapes in the master layout associated with the slide, then build a dictionary of alternative text, based on some finger printing of the shape. Using the fingerprint (example: font size, alignment, font color...) I can get around that alternative text and tags don't carry over from master to the slides.

I noted that this only works with placeholders. Text boxes placed on the master slide don't even exist in the slide context, so the method here only works as the user don't mess with formatting.

```vb
''
''  inspired by
''  https://superuser.com/questions/1719032/powerpoint-slides-shapes-dont-seem-to-inherit-alternative-text-from-master/1719213#1719213
''
Sub updateSlide()


    Dim osl As Slide
    Dim d As Dictionary   ' need reference to MS scripting library
    
    Dim osh As Shape
    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim mykey As String
    
    Set d = Nothing
    
    ' Set d = New Dictionary
    
    ' loop over every slide
    For Each osl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        '
        ' make a dictionary of customtexts in the master
        '
        Set d = makedictionary(osl.CustomLayout)
    
        ' loop over shapes
        ' and find using properties like size / font...
        For Each osh In osl.Shapes
              mykey = makeKEY(osh)
              
              ' if found, do something with this shape.
              If Len(d(mykey)) > 0 Then
                If ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Count < 1 Then
                   osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "  -  "
                Else
                   ' can also replace with other presentation data.
                   ' 
                   osh.TextFrame.TextRange.Text = ActivePresentation.SectionProperties.Name(osl.sectionIndex)
                End If
              End If
        Next 'shapes
    Next 'slide
End Sub



''
''  make a fingerprint of a shape
''
Function makeKEY(oShape As Shape) As String
    ' return some variables from this one
    ' independent of position !
    ' this is like a "fingerprint" of the shape.
    With oShape.TextFrame.TextRange
        ' choose something that is UNIQUE to the shape
        makeKEY = .Font.Name & .ParagraphFormat.Alignment & .Font.Color & .Font.Italic
    End With
End Function


''
''  make a dictionary of shapes with an alternative text.
''  so we don't have to loop the same objects many times.
''

Function makedictionary(masterslide As CustomLayout) As Dictionary
    ' make a new dict
    Dim d As Dictionary
    Set d = New Dictionary
    Dim mSh As Shape
    
    For Each mSh In masterslide.Shapes
            If Len(mSh.AlternativeText) > 0 Then
               mykey = makeKEY(mSh)
               d(mykey) = mSh.AlternativeText
            End If
    Next
    
    Set makedictionary = d
    Set d = Nothing

End Function
```